# Convert an array into image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a 2Darray  named `C` containing pixels in its indexes. How to view the image
that is formed by that pixels value, A image can be represented by array. No w i am trying the reverse process, I wanna see only **grayscale image** since array named `C` has only one value per index. Doing programming in python

Here goes my code
http://pastebin.com/qmnKrtzu

getting error in this line

```
ime = Image.fromarray(c)
ime.save("your_file.jpeg")
```

`ime = Image.fromarray(c_array)`
`arr = obj.__array_interface__
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__array_interface__'`

Comment: Are you wanting to save your array as an image (for example as a png)? or wanting to just display it?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: I want to do both save and display

Comment: @Prune thanks http://pastebin.com/DCJWqJpk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's **much** better with the code; thanks.  In the future, please remember to cut down the code to the minimal level and post it in the original question.  An external link doesn't get nearly as much attention.

Your problem is that **Image.fromarray** requires an array as input; you gave it a list.  You did originally convert your list, **c**, to an array, but you didn't keep the array.  I think you need this at lines 18 and 41 from your pastebin code, where I've added references to c_array:

```
c = [[0]*k*im.width for i in range(k*im.height)]
c_array = np.asarray(c)
...
ime = Image.fromarray(c_array)
ime.save("your_file.jpeg")
```

Comment: Done but faced with new problems thatis,getting error while saving the file and the error is IOError("cannot write mode %s as JPEG" % im.mode)

Comment: Okay ... new problem, post a new question.  Follow that MCVE link.  I don't know how many people would dig through these indirections to solve a secondary problem.  You haven't given us the code needed to reproduce the problem, and I don't have it here.

Comment: i edited the question and updated the link.. thanks for the mcve link. Iwould follow in the future

Comment: This should really be another question.  The comments and answer here refer to the original question; now it looks like we're all inebriated.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use c.**values** to convert dataframe into an array

> ```
> ime = Image.fromarray(c.values)
> ime.save("your_file.jpeg")
> ```